# Calculating normals for Catmull-Clark

Tags: graphics, normals

I'm not calculating my normals correctly after doing a catmull-clark iteration. I'm not sure about the right approach to fix this.

Right now, I'm performing my subdivision first, getting the vertices in the draw_vertices and then calling calculate normals on those draw_vertices.

how to figure out the right orientation for each quad?

[image]

[image]

```
void calculate_normals() {
        for (int i = 0; i < d(); i+=4) {
            vec3 a = d[i];
            vec3 b = d[i+1];
            vec3 c = d[i+2];
            vec3 d = d[i+3];
            vec3 ba = b - a;
            vec3 ca = c - a;
            vec3 normal1;
            cross(&normal1, &ca, &ba);
            normal1.normalize();
            n.push_back(normal1);
            n.push_back(normal1);
            n.push_back(normal1);
            n.push_back(normal1);

            d[i].print();
            d[i+1].print();
            d[i+2].print();
            d[i+3].print();
            normal1.print();
            normal1.print();
            normal1.print();
            normal1.print();
            printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the normal of each face and assign that for each vertex. Since vertices are connected to four different faces, assigning the normal of one face to the vertex does not provide the right answer. You should calculate the normal of each face connected to a vertex and take an average. In addition, if the vertices are set in a counter clock wise order c=b.cross(a)

Comment: Vector3f a = (*v1)->pos;
Vector3f b = (*v2)->pos;
Vector3f c = (*v3)->pos;
 Vector3f d = (*v4)->pos;
Vector3f normal1;
Vector3f da = d - a;
Vector3f ba = b - a;
cross(&normal1, &da, &ba);
...
            (*v1)->normal = (*v1)->normal + normal1;
            (*v2)->normal = (*v2)->normal + normal2;
            (*v3)->normal = (*v3)->normal + normal3;
            (*v4)->normal = (*v4)->normal + normal4;

Comment: Technically, it should work. This is the concept of normal calculation for Phong and Gouraud shading. Check this out: http://www.nbb.cornell.edu/neurobio/land/OldStudentProjects/cs490-95to96/guo/report.html. In general, it seems that some normals are upwards and some are downwards. Try to render them and make sure, they are accurate.